django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/app/.apt/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2
My django heroku app is building but fails during the release process with the error below.
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/app/.apt/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1' : filo.2.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") 
I am using vscode in windows. I followed the CodeWithMosh process and I can run the db in dev mode on my machine.
Below is a snip of the requirements.txt file.
Django==5.0.3
django-filter==23.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
docopt==0.6.2
pymssql==2.2.11
pyodbc==5.1.0
sqlparse==0.4.4

virtualenv==20.25.1

My AptFile is configuration is below.
`unixodbc
unixodbc-dev
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql18/msodbcsql18_18.3.2.1-1_arm64.deb`

I have installed the MSSQL build pack and the associated UBUNTU build packs.
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/app/.apt/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1' : filo.2.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
The first buildpack: ``https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
The second buildpack: ``https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
The last buildpack: ``https://github.com/heroku-softtrends/heroku-python-pyodbc-buildpack.git
Heroku support states this outside of their support (which I find... uh unfortunate).
Any thoughts or suggestions are most welcome. Thx
I have re-ran pipenv install pyodbc and pip freeze requirements.txt, but still have the same release fail after a successful build.
remote: -----> Starting adding ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server remote:
-----> copied libmsodbcsql-18-*
remote: -----> copied msodbcsqlr18.rll remote: -----> copied profile.d remote: ----->
Finished adding ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
remote: ----->
Discovering process types remote:        Procfile declares types ->
release, web
remote: remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:
Done: 182.4M remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Release
command declared: this new release will not be available until the
command succeeds.
remote:        Released v90 remote:
https://xxx.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote:
Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command
django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/app/.apt/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
